# How do I force offlineimap to use python2.7?

Tags: debian, python, offlineimap

I'm setting up a new computer and installed `offlineimap` with `pip install --user offlineimap` but when I try to run it I'm getting a series of errors because offlineimap doesn't support Python3:

https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/issues/472

I do have 2.7 installed as well as 3:

```
amanda@host:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

but even I'm not sure how to force offlineimap to use it.

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version I uninstalled and tried to reinstall, specifying the python version, but that's choking in its own special way:

```
amanda@host:~$ python2.7 ~/.local/bin/pip install --user offlineimap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amanda/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
```

The full OfflineIMAP error:

```
OfflineIMAP 7.2.1
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
imaplib2 v2.57 (bundled), Python v3.6.5, OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
Account sync Example:
 *** Processing account Example
 Establishing connection to mail.example.info:993 (VelRemote)
 ERROR: While attempting to sync account 'Example'
  IMAP4 protocol error: program error: <class 'TypeError'> - cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
 *** Finished account 'Example' in 0:00
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: While attempting to sync account 'Example'
  IMAP4 protocol error: program error: <class 'TypeError'> - cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

Traceback:
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 283, in syncrunner
    self.__sync()
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 359, in __sync
    remoterepos.getfolders()
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 452, in getfolders
    imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 547, in acquireconnection
    af=self.af,
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/imaplibutil.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(WrappedIMAP4_SSL, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 2183, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, debug, debug_file, identifier, timeout, debug_buf_lvl)
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 400, in __init__
    self.welcome = self._request_push(name='welcome', tag='continuation').get_response('IMAP4 protocol error: %s')[1]
  File "/home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 201, in get_response
    raise typ(exc_fmt % str(val))
```

Comment: Please add `cat /home/amanda/.local/bin/pip`.

Answer (score 1):

The installed Python 3 offlineimap is taking precedence over the installed Python 2.

For deleting the Python 3 version, do:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/amanda/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/offlineimap*
```

After this, hopefully it should now pickup the Python 2 version.

#### Known issue

As for your error using `pip`, is a Debian/Ubuntu known issue.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

or

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

should fix it; as the OP also stated, after deleting the Python 3 offlinemap package, the Python 2 version was installed with `apt` instead of `pip` with:

```
sudo apt install offlineimap
```

Comment: I didn't want to screw up the rest of my  Python just for this so I tried just installing with `sudo apt install offlineimap` which worked fine. (I had already removed the offending Py3.6 package)

Comment: @Amanda correcting you `pip` wont screw up it. Eventually you will have to correct it, if it is not working correctly it will impact you in the short-medium term.

Comment: Question: why would I use `rm` and not `pip uninstall`? The latter actually captures a few more files.

Comment: Ideally, `pip` would install 2.7 packages, while `pip3` installs 3.6 packages. But pip isn't broken, it's just assuming I want to default to py3.

Comment: @Amanda The default is python 2. It is "broken" in a sense some configuration change it´s behaviour, and many apps and instructions expect it to handle python 2, as you have found out.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up `pip*`

```
$ python3 -m pip uninstall pip
$ python -m pip uninstall pip
```

The `~/.local/bin/pip` should be removed.

Reinstall `pip` locally:

```
$ curl -LO https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py --user
```

Install your package:

```
$ python2.7 ~/.local/bin/pip install --user offlineimap
```

Comment: This assumed I don't want my default to be python3, though, right?

Comment: @Amanda Just it will reinstall `pip`.